# Docker containter route with Traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

On my Docker container I want use multiple Traefik routing rules "traefik.frontend.rule=EXPR" to route a specific host (example.com) and path (/phpmyadmin/) to the container. So "example.com/phpmyadmin/" will be routed to the container.

I would expect something like the following to work

```
traefik.frontend.rule=Host:exmple.com,Path:/phpmyadmin/
```

However, this makes the container available for example.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use semicolon as the delimiter rather than comma

```
traefik.frontend.rule=Host:exmple.com;Path:/phpmyadmin/
```